# toggleButton on status displays odd graphic

Tags: android, button

I have created a toggle button with different text for off/on:

```
<ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/PTT_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="pushtotalk"
        android:text="@string/ptt" 
        android:textOn="Push To Talk On"
        android:textOff="Push To Talk Off"/>

                  ...

public void pushtotalk(View view) {
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();     
    if (on) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        // etc
}
```

When the toggle is off the button looks ok, however when I toggle on the light blue appears outside the box, what is happening here?

[image]

Edit: default toggle button, no custom image.

EDIT perhaps something got to do with the layout the button is in constraining it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout
android:id="@+id/top_lvl_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>

   <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/mainFrame"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingRight="6dip"
        >

        <!-- (1) inCallPanel: the main set of in-call UI elements -->
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/inCallPanel"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        >

            <!-- Slide hints: if the "sliding card" feature is enabled,
                 one or the other of these is visible at any given moment
                 (see updateCardSlideHints()). -->

            <!-- Slide hint and arrow *above* the main body of the card,
                 shown when the card is in the *bottom* position. -->
            <!-- This hint's position onscreen is static: the Y value is set
                 so that the hint will be visible just above the top edge of
                 the CallCard when the CallCard is in the "bottom" position.
                 The resources here describe the portrait mode layout; see
                 InCallScreen.ConfigurationHelper.applyConfigurationToLayout()
                 for the differences in landscape mode. -->
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/slideUp"
                          android:orientation="vertical"
                          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                          android:background="@null"
                          android:visibility="gone"
                          >
                <TextView android:id="@+id/slideUpHint"
                          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                          android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Slide hint and arrow *below* the main body of the card,
                 shown when the card is in the *top* position. -->
            <!-- This hint's position onscreen is static: the Y value is set
                 so that the hint will be visible just below the bottom edge of
                 the CallCard when the CallCard is in the "top" position.
                 The resources here describe the portrait mode layout; see
                 InCallScreen.ConfigurationHelper.applyConfigurationToLayout()
                 for the differences in landscape mode. -->
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/slideDown"
                          android:orientation="vertical"
                          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                           android:background="@null"
                          android:visibility="gone"
                          >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/slideDownHint"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />                
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/stats"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
               <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/codec"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>  <!-- End of inCallPanel -->

    </FrameLayout>  <!-- End of mainFrame -->

    <!-- The sliding drawer control containing the DTMF dialer.  This has been
         moved so that it is a sibling of mainFrame, instead of being a child.
         Doing so allows us to expand to the full width of the screen, instead
         of being confined to the mainFrame's layout -->
    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/dialer_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:topOffset="5px"
        android:bottomOffset="7px"
        android:handle="@+id/dialer_tab"
        android:content="@+id/dtmf_dialer"
        android:allowSingleTap="false">

       <ImageButton
           android:id="@id/dialer_tab"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_dialpad_tray"
           android:background="@drawable/tray_handle_normal"/>

        <include
            layout="@layout/dtmf_twelve_key_dialer"
            android:id="@id/dtmf_dialer"/>

    </SlidingDrawer>


    <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/PTT_button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="pushtotalk2"
            android:text="@string/ptt2" 
            android:layout_x="20dp"
        android:layout_y="400dp"
            android:textOn="Push To Talk On"
            android:textOff="Push To Talk Off"/>      

      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="150dp"
        android:layout_y="400dp"
        android:ems="10" >



        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the button's background image your own 9patch?
I would suggest that the 9patch is not created correctly. I had a similar problem (with my custom components however) and redrawing the 9patch helped. I just didn't draw properly the black dots which define how 9patch is allowed to resize.

https://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: Thanks, but this is just a default togglebutton!

Comment: Hm that's really weird. I am curious about how does the image look like when you shorten/extend button's text?

Comment: the blue bar in the background just keeps following the length of the button, thought this would work as standard :|

Comment: Really can't help you more. From info you provided it seems to me like the aforementioned 9patch is really drawn incorrectly. If I were you I would draw my own. You may also review the `btn_toggle*9.png` files in your Android SDK. In my case: `cd /opt/android-sdk-linux && find -name 'btn_toggle*9.png'`

Comment: thanks I'll have a look, that found quite a lot of files! So I'll maybe have to draw my own. Very weird, I assume this happens to other people but i dont even know what to google haha.

Comment: One more think. Which version of Android do you have?

Comment: on the phone is jellybean, I am building against an older version. Ill make a project with just a toggle button, see what happens.

Comment: posted the code above, I feel that the layout is messing with the button someehow